# How to url-decode a URL in Yii?

Tags: php, yii, yii-url-manager

How to parse the URL which in the format as shown

```
http://localhost/CorrectCodeToDeploy/healthkatta/index.php?r=site%2FArticle%2F2013%2F07%2F13%2FDisadvantages-of-smoking-51e12690a5a58
```

I want to get rid of the special characters `%2F` and put `/` instead.

I have shared a link of an article to Facebook
but when I access this link from Facebook it comes in the format as mentioned above and the content is not properly accessed in Yii. How can I write the pattern to access this kind of URL in Yii?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can directly decode your $_GET in your index.php file, something like:

```
$_GET = array_map('urldecode', $_GET);
```

Please be aware the above doesn't work with nested arrays, so you need to create a more in depth recursive function like (not tested though) :

```
function urldecodeArray($strArr){
    if (!is_string($strArr) && !is_array($strArr)) {
       return $strArr;
    }
    if(is_string($strArr)) {
        return urldecode($strArr);
    }
    foreach ($strArr as $key=>$value) {
       $strArr[$key] = urldecodeArray($value);
    }
    return $strArr;
}
$_GET = urldecodeArray($_GET);
```

Comment: i just did. Yii has index.php file, which is the bootstrap file. Add it in there, before you require the yii framework.

Answer (score 1):

You can just to use `urldecode()` function

Comment: Where to place that code when i click the link posted in facebook i get that url

Comment: As I'm understand, You post your link in FB. Try to decode/encode url in code, where send your link to FB.